# Revert package from building with Rcpp to building without Rcpp in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, rcpp

For an internal development project I am building a package. I was curious about building it with rcpp, but didn't actually use any cpp files. As the attachment policies of our mail server does not allow executables, I would like to stop building the package with the resulting .dll (win architecture), but am not able to revert. Anybody have any suggestions (except copying into a fresh rstudio project)?

Comment: Is there any C or Fortran in there too? Because you won't get a DLL unless there's some of that kicking around too...

Comment: That would still be in the `src/` folder. See my first bullet point below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That can't be hard:

- delete `src/`
- remove `LinkingTo:` and `Imports:` in `DESCRIPTION`
- remove the `useDynLib` instruction, and `importFrom(Rcpp, ...)` in `NAMESPACE`

and wait all the extra time for your non-Rcpp package to finish running :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I already did that. Wen I build the win library, I still get the  lib folder in the zip and a .dll. I suspect that the package is now flagged build a dll within RStudio.

Comment: Nope.  RStudio just calls `R CMD build` like the rest of us.  Computers are still deterministic.

Comment: We suspect something is up. If there's no src folder, then there's nothing to compile, so there should be no dll. What's in it? Can you inspect the symbols in it? Can you see the command that builds it?  Something is not doing what you think its doing.

Comment: As expected, this was a UTS-error (user too stupid) - affter deleting the old zip and rebuilding, the build is indeed free of the /lib folder. Seems that the old zip file hab been amended, but not cleaned.